# Save data received from view through ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On abort in controller, this is the format for javascript object I'm getting from the Ajax call:

```
{
        "j_identifier" = > "24942",
        "charge" = > {
          "0" = > {
                  "complainant" = > "",
                  "address" = > "",
                  "name" = > "",
                  "agency" = > "",
                  "codefendant" = > {
                    "0" = > {
                            "name" = > "sdfsdsd",
                            "address" = > "fsdf",
                            "phone" = > "sdf"
                    },
                    "1" = > {
                           "name" = > "sdfs",
                           "address" = > "sdfs",
                           "phone" = > "sdf"
                    }
                  }
          },
          "1" = > {
                  "complainant" = > "",
                  "address" = > "",
                  "name" = > "",
                  "agency" = > "",
                  "codefendant" = > {
                    "0" = > {
                            "name" = > "sdfsdsd",
                            "address" = > "fsdf",
                            "phone" = > "sdf"
                    },
                    "1" = > {
                           "name" = > "sdfs",
                           "address" = > "sdfs",
                           "phone" = > "sdf"
                    }
                  }
         }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm doing to get the data and save it:

```
 jcharge = params[:charge]
 if !jcharge.nil?
    jcharge.each do |key,charge|
         e = JCharge.new(charge)
         e.cmap_id = data.id
         e.save
         charge_id = e.id
         codefd = charge.codefendant
         if !codefd.nil?
              codefd.each do |k,codef|
                  cod = JuCharge.new(codef)
                  cod.jucharge_id = data.id
                  cod.save                       
              end
         end

     end
 end
```

I'm getting this parsing error:

```
   undefined method `codefendant' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x44b5ab0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `charge` is a Hash. You can access its values using square brackets:

```
charge.codefendant # undefined method
charge[:codefendant] #=> ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the concept of hash that was the issue.